# Getting message: "Match failed [400]", errorType: "Meteor.Error" when using rocketchat methods(loadHistory) in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, meteor, rocket.chat, ddp

I am trying to integrate Rocket chat to my application using [asteroid](https://github.com/mondora/asteroid) but when I use Rocket.chat's [LoadHistory method](https://rocket.chat/docs/developer-guides/realtime-api/method-calls/load-history/) I get `{isClientSafe: true, error: 400, reason: "Match failed", message: "Match failed [400]", errorType: "Meteor.Error"}`. To be clear, I have never used Rocket.chat or Asteroid before. However some methods are working flawlessly.

```
/**
 * Calls a server-side method with the specified arguments.
 * @param method  string required: the name of the method to call
 * @param params  [param1, param2, ...] any optional: parameters passed to the 
   server method
 * @return Promise resolved, rejected
*/
let asteroidMethods = function (method, param){
  return socket.call(method, param)
};

getMessageHistory = (lastMessage) => {
  let param =[ lastMessage.rid, null, 50, lastMessage['ts']['$date']];
  asteroidMethods("loadHistory", param).then(res=>{
    console.log(res)
  }).catch(e=>{
    console.log(e)
  })
}
```

Comment: What does `console.log(param)` print before calling `loadHistory`?

Answer (score 2):

Since the `Match failed` response is a rather generic one, there're several potential issues causing your error. For example, the `lastMessage.rid` could be empty.

With your problem, the Rocket.Chat **server logs** shall give you more information about the underlaying problem. For that, Rocket.Chat offers a nice way of accessing the server logs through the user interface:

- Log in to the Rocket.Chat admin UI as admin user
- Ensure the `Log Level` to be very verbose -> Level `2` (https://example.com/admin/Logs)
- Visit the log view (https://example.com/admin/view-logs)
- Execute your code once

**Example**

I've set my `roomId` to `42` in an example request:

```
connection.method('loadHistory', [42, roomId, oldestMessageDate, 15])
```

That triggers the following log event with very detailed information:

```
Exception while invoking method 'loadHistory'
{ Error: Match error: Expected string, got number }
```

With that information, you should be able to identify the actual issue behind your request.